# Qlik Sense Setup with Different Database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, postgresql, qliksense

Qlik Sense installs PostgreSQL with embedded way. Is there an option to use another database instead of PostgreSQL? (like oracle or msSql).

I read and I couldn't find. But hope to hear someone have an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to install Qlik Sense other than "PostgreSQL" (version June 2017)